# PHP File Write - Error Message Every Time

Tags: php, file

So here's my code keep hitting my error message, have fiddled with permissions but no luck, any ideas?

```php
<?php
//create variables
$first_name = (int) $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = (int) $_POST['last_name'];
$document_root = $_SERVER['/var/www'];
$date = date('H:i, jS F Y');
?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>We get the message...</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>We get the message . . .</h1>
    <?php
        $output_string = $date."\t".$first_name.$last_name."   \t".$message."\n";
        @$fp = fopen("$document_root-messages.txt", 'w+');
        if (!$fp) {
            echo "<p>apologies</p>";
            exit;
        }
        flock($fp, LOCK_EX);
        fwrite($fp, $output_string, strlen($output_string));
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fflush($fp);
        fclose($fp);

        echo "<p>message written.</p>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure that you have the required permissions on the folder?

Comment: It looks like you are writing to a file called `/var/www-messages.txt`. I am assuming you meant that to be `/var/www/messages.txt`? `$fp = fopen("$document_root/messages.txt", 'w+');` and notice I removed the `@` error suppression.

Comment: If that actually was your intent, it is very dangerous to allow the web server write access directly to `/var`. Even writing inside `/var/www` is quite risky, as all other files there will explicitly need to be made non-writable by the web server user.

Comment: I've created the messages.txt file already and chown to the www-data user. Don't know what else I should be doing permissions wise. What does removing the @ actually do? The folder permissions are still with the local user, the web server user only has write permission to the messages.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

```
@$fp = fopen("$document_root-messages.txt", 'w+');
```

You didn't actually make a path, there's no such file as:

```
/var/www-messages.txt
```

This is now a real path:

```
@$fp = fopen("$document_root/messages.txt", 'w+');
```

And is I assume what you meant, assuming the file in /var/www is message.txt.

The comments about the bad practice of making /var/www writable are also correct, it's best when learning to start out with good practices, since if you start with bad ones, you just have to unlearn them anyway, and that's more work.

The  way to avoid this is to just get used to being more clear, like so:

```
$file_path = $document_root . '/messages.txt';
echo $file_path . '<br>';
@$fp = fopen($file_path, 'w+');
```

Then you get rid of the echo after it's working, the echo is also good advice. If you get used to cramming all the actions inside of something, it's very hard to debug, if you construct your strings outside of say fopen, then you can debug the path by echoing it, and you don't get all confused. Notice how clear that is, and how easy to debug?

Comment: Just to add a debugging tip:  next time try adding an echo to see the actual value of your path, before asking here on SO.

Comment: Also good advice, I updated to include a better way to code it so it can be debugged with echoes etc.